# Typescript failure when checking boolean value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in a typescript module:

```
if (!(wholeWords === true)) { 
  console.log("Any part", wholeWords); 
} else { 
  console.log("Whole word", wholeWords); }
```

The "wholeWords" parameter is declared in the argument list for the method as a boolean. (wholeWords: boolean)

In my browser, I see the following:

```
Any part true
```

How is this possible?!?

Comment: Side note, why not write this as `if (wholeWords) {} else {}` - actual suggestion - can you log `wholeWords` before the check? If you set `wholeWords = true;` right before the logic, does it work?

Comment: Add `console.log(typeof wholeWords)` before that code and see what it returns.  I'm making a *wild guess* that `wholeWords` is actually the string value `"true"` at runtime, and where you *think* you've guaranteed that `wholeWords` is a `boolean` is not actually doing it.  Provide more of your code if you want more help.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect wholeWords is the *string* `"true"` and not the boolean value `true`

```js
var wholeWords = "true";

if (!(wholeWords === true)) { 
  console.log("Any part", wholeWords); 
} else { 
  console.log("Whole word", wholeWords);
}
```

Comment: I think you're right. I have an Angular dropdown as follows:

    <select class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="wholeWords">
    <option value="true">Whole Words Only</option>
    <option value="true">Any Match</option>
    </select>

That dropdown is bound to a boolean value that's used in the filter. However, I was able to confirm that it's passing a string. However, I'm confused. Typescript is supposed to enforce STRONG TYPING. What's happening here?

Comment: Typescript compiles to plain JS, which has no types. So there is no runtime enforcement of your types. In this case, what likely happened is that somewhere you had a value of type `any` that got assigned to `boolean`. Typescript is okay with that since an `any` certainly can be a `boolean`. But, in this case, it turned out to be a string. In other words, to get the most from typescript, make sure you limit the use of `any` as much as you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing using `===` you're checking if it's **equal value and equal type**.

Try with:

```
if (!(wholeWords == true)) { 
  console.log("Any part", wholeWords); 
} else { 
  console.log("Whole word", wholeWords);
}
```